# Adding a struct to an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Given a struct `Element`:

```
typedef struct {
    char someString[9]
    int value;
} Element
```

and an array `elementList`:

```
Element elementList[5];
```

is there an easy way to dynamically add an Element to each index of the list? I have tried creating a function `add_element` that takes in the list and modifies it there but I'd prefer something equivalent to Java's `elementList[i] = new Element`.

Comment: each part of that array is *already* an element. You do not need to do "new", memory has already been allocated and `elementList[1]` can be addressed directly (although it may contain rubbish unless you initialize it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need, that array *consists* of structure instances.

You can do e.g.:

```
strcpy(elementList[0].someString, "foo");
elementList[0].value = 4711;
```

This is not possible in Java, where everything is a reference, but in C you can do this. If you *want* a bunch of `NULL`-able references, in C you use pointers:

```
Element *elementList[5]; /* An array of 5 pointers to type Element. */
```

Then you have to use e.g. heap allocations to make sure there is memory before accessing the `Element`:

```
elementList[0] = malloc(sizeof *elementList[0]); /* This might fail! */
elementList[0]->value = 17;
```

Answer (score 1):

As declared, you've created a 5-element array of `Element` *instances*; there's no need to allocate new `Element` objects.  You can go ahead and read/assign each member of each element:

```
element[i].value = some_value();
strcpy( element[i].someString, some_string() );
```

If you *want* to emulate the Java method, you'd do something like the following:

```
Element *elementList[5]; // create elementList as an array of *pointers* to Element
...
elementList[i] = malloc( sizeof *elementList[i] ); // dynamically allocate each element
```

Note that in this case, you'd use the `->` operator instead of the `.` operator to access each `Element` member, since each `elementList[i]` is a *pointer* to `Element`, not an `Element` instance:

```
elementList[i]->value = some_value();
strcpy( elementList[i]->someString, some_string() );
```

In either case, the array size is fixed; you cannot grow or shrink the number of elements in the array.